# Slick2D does not render all MouseOverAreas

Tags: java, slick2d

I am writing a small game in Java using Slick2D.

For my MainMenu I have 4 buttons and I use `MouseOverAreas` to represent these buttons.
The problem is that the last `MouseOverArea` I create is not rendered.

I render them like this

```
@Override
public void render(GameContainer container, StateBasedGame game, Graphics g) throws SlickException {
    this.renderButtons(container, g);
}

private void renderButtons(GameContainer container, Graphics g) {
    this.buttonStartGame.render(container, g);
    this.buttonSettings.render(container, g);
    this.buttonAchievements.render(container, g);
    this.buttonClose.render(container, g);
}
```

But `buttonClose` is not rendered... I create the buttons like this

```
@Override
public void init(GameContainer container, StateBasedGame game) throws SlickException {
    this.initButtons(container);
}

private void initButtons(GameContainer container) throws SlickException {
    this.buttonStartGame = createButton(container, "Start Game", 0);
    this.buttonSettings = createButton(container, "Settings", 1);
    this.buttonAchievements = createButton(container, "Achievements", 2);
    this.buttonClose = createButton(container, "Exit", 3);

//      MouseOverArea foobar = createButton(container, "Foobar", 5);
}

private MouseOverArea createButton(GameContainer container, String text, int buttonIndex) throws SlickException {
    /* x, y, width and height are calculated so that I can use them.
       They all are local variables with the right values but the code for them is not important */

    Image image = new Image(width, height);
    Graphics g = image.getGraphics();

    int textX = (width - g.getFont().getWidth(text)) / 2;
    int textY = (height - g.getFont().getHeight(text)) / 2;

    g.drawString(text, textX, textY);

    MouseOverArea button = new MouseOverArea(container, image, x, y, width, height, this::onComponentActivated);
    button.setNormalColor(Color.white);
    button.setMouseOverColor(Color.gray);
    button.setMouseDownColor(Color.darkGray);

    return button;
}
```

However, if I also create this `foobar` the close-button will be rendered.
Am I missing something or why is the last `MouseOverArea` I create never renderable?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why, but calling `g.destroy()` did the job